# How to capitalize first letter razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, capitalization

I am new to MVC and have not found a solution for this online.

I have the html as :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address1) <br />
```

I want all the first letter of address1 to be capital letters e.g. Something Road instead of something road.

Now I have a class client and property Address1 and using EF to get the address as follow:

```
 public class MyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: What about http://www.dotnetperls.com/uppercase-first-letter ?

Comment: I understand that but in MVC as I said i cannot do this in html and the property itself...as my values are coming from db with dbcontext

Comment: @Sam1 use a wrapper class- a view model that wraps the model.

Comment: @dbaseman can you post an example please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to keep the presentation layer and the data access layer separate.  Create a view model that wraps or translates the ORM / entity framework objects.

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
    private Client _dao;

    public ClientViewModel(Client dao)
    {
        _dao = dao;
    }

    public string Address 
    { 
        get
        {
            // modify the address as needed here
            return _dao.Address;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I do it this way would that mean I can validate all my properties...say one of my property is empty string and in html output dont want to show it would this be possible?

Comment: @Sam1 I saw your other question -- that's really an issue with the view, but yes, you should be able to do that.

Comment: Hi, have done it this way so how do I call Address  in my view now?

Comment: @Sam1 Same way, `@Html.DisplayFrom(model => model.Address)`.  Use Robuust's answer to format the string.

Answer (score 20):

easy solution could be

```
Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control" } })
```

then use below css to capitalize your first letter then you done.

```
.form-control {
text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this is so far down. Why is everyone trying to handle a **styling** concern with view models?

Comment: This solution is beautiful in its simplicity

Answer (score 6):

You could add a partial class for `Client` with a property that returns `Address1` in title case:

```
public partial class Client
{
    public string TitleCaseAddress1
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(this.Address1);
        }
    }
}
```

You would then use `TitleCaseAddress1` in your Razor:

`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TitleCaseAddress1) <br />`

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking to do this strictly in Razor, this example is converting the logged-in user name.  Replace with your string variable.

**This gets first letter and converts to upper:**

```
@(@User.Identity.GetUserName().ToString().Substring(0, 1).ToUpper())
```

**This gets the remaining string.**

```
@(@User.Identity.GetUserName().ToString().Substring(1, 
    User.Identity.GetUserName().ToString().Length - 1))
```

**Just put them together like so to get the whole string.**

```
@(@User.Identity.GetUserName().ToString().Substring(0, 
    1).ToUpper())@(@User.Identity.GetUserName().ToString().Substring(1, 
    User.Identity.GetUserName().ToString().Length - 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the **correct** way to accomplish what you want, I've implemented it for you.

There is an `HtmlStringFormatter.Create()` which allow you to pass a delegate and make your own anonymous formatter.

**Code Sample:**

```
// This just upper case all the letters.
@Html.DisplayFormatFor(model => model.Address, HtmlStringFormatter.Create(s=> s.ToUpper()))
```

If You to create a custom formatter, derive from `HtmlStringFormatter` and set its delegate property to whatever manipulation you want to do.

**Code Sample:**

```
// Here I use the Capital Letter custom formatter.
@Html.DisplayFormatFor(model => model.Address, new CapitalLetterFormatter())
```

**All the classes:**

```
namespace MvcPlay.HelperExtensions
{
    public static class HelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayFormatFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, HtmlStringFormatter formatter)
        {
            var output = helper.DisplayFor(expression);
            string formatted = formatter.Delegate.Invoke(output.ToString());
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(formatted);
        }
    }
}

namespace MvcPlay.HtmlStringFormatting
{
    public class HtmlStringFormatter
    {
        public delegate string FormatDelegate(string s);

        public FormatDelegate Delegate;
        public Expression<FormatDelegate> formatExpression;

        private HtmlStringFormatter(FormatDelegate expression)
        {
            Delegate = expression;
        }

        protected HtmlStringFormatter()
        {

        }

        public static HtmlStringFormatter Create(FormatDelegate expression)
        {
            return new HtmlStringFormatter(expression);
        }
    }

    public class CapitalLetterFormatter : HtmlStringFormatter
    {
        public CapitalLetterFormatter()
        {
            Delegate =
                s => new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the following lines to the Web.Config at the Views folder:

```
<add namespace="MvcPlay.HelperExtensions" />
<add namespace="MvcPlay.HtmlStringFormatting"/>
```

This will include the Formatters and the Helper Extension automatically so you won't need to include it inside every view that you want to use it in.

Comment: no comment? anyway, Have a look on my solution - it is way more reusable and doesn't require to create ViewModels each time you want to show a data in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use C# code for this: example from: http://www.dotnetperls.com/uppercase-first-letter

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(UppercaseFirst("samuel"));
    Console.WriteLine(UppercaseFirst("julia"));
    Console.WriteLine(UppercaseFirst("john smith"));
    }

    static string UppercaseFirst(string s)
    {
    // Check for empty string.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    // Return char and concat substring.
    return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: and how would I do it using MVC?

Comment: in MVC you can add c# code blocks. Do you know the basics already of MVC projects or .NET aspx? - I don't have VS2010 available here so I cannot create your code right away. I can tomorrow, if nobody did it before me. Or if you didn't find the solution yourself by then.

Comment: I can wait till tomorrow as I said am new to mvc bt have experience with asp.net

Comment: Works well in Razor:  `@char.ToUpper(s[0])s.Substring(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use as follows

```
@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(sampleText)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the original question referred to capitalizing every word in the whole string. But, I got here trying to find a solution to capitalizing the first letter of a string. I agreed with kiflay's answer as the best solution to the OP. But, expanded on it to modify only the first letter, in my usage.

CSS:

```
blockquote::first-letter {
text-transform: capitalize;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap 4.x with Razor you use CSS to capitalize the first letter:

```
<p class="text-capitalize">CapiTaliZed text.</p>
```