# Capitalize letter of string in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have one string which is class course type as "database subject".I want to display it as "Database Subject" means capitalize the string. And given string is dynamic.

```
foreach (var registration in Model.Registrations)
{
   <br /><text> - -@registration.Class.Type.Course</text>
   // Database Subject  
}
```

I want to implement above changes in razor view.

Comment: Please paste the class of `Type`. Usually I do this in the controller, in case I need to expose the same data to an API, the display would be the same.  If you *know* for fact that you aren't going to expose this data let me know.  There are some great ways to do this without having to add tons of code to your Razor pages (like using `ToTitleCase` on every page, don't do that).

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712875/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-razor

Comment: this answer to be specific : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32180052/1875256

Comment: I cant use CSS or not make string as Capitalize in .cs file

Comment: I have use following code to display string in capital letters in razor view.

@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(registration.Class.Type.Course)